# $|X_n|\implies |X|$ implies $\mathbb{P}[|X_n|>t]\to\mathbb{P}[|X|>t]$ for all but countably many > $t$.

Tags: probability-theory

I was reading a proof of the theorem ("$\implies$" is the weak convergence of random variables)

> If $X_n\implies X$, then $\mathbb{E}|X|\le\liminf_n E|X_n|$

which starts by saying

> By the mapping theorem,$|X_n|\implies |X|$, and therefore
> $\mathbb{P}[|X_n|>t]\to\mathbb{P}[|X|>t]$ for all but countably many
> $t$.

I was wondering why. These are my thoughts : If $\mu_n(A)=\mathbb{P}(X_n\in A)$ is the distribution of the random variable, by the portemanteau lemma, we have $\mathbb{P}[|X_n|>t]=\mu_n((t,\infty))\to\mu((t,\infty))=\mathbb{P}[|X|>t]$ if $(t,\infty)$ is a continuity set.  We have $\partial(t,\infty)=\{t\}$ so we have to show that $\mathbb{P}(|X|=t)=0$ for all but countably many $t$. This is because if $P(|X|=t)>0$ for uncountably many $t$ then the probability of the whole space would be infinite so different from 1.

Is it okay to see it like this?

Comment: This is an immediate application of the Portmanteau theorem. Notice that there are at most a countable number of discontinuities for $g(t)=P[|X|>y]$ (why?)

Comment: following what @JoseAlivez said : because it is a monotone function

Comment: Yes, that is why. I was just trying to give you a generous hint.

Comment: thanks, my reasoning was correct though?

Comment: Yes, that is why I mentioned the Portmanteau theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement $X_n \Longrightarrow X$ is equivalent to $F_{X_n}(x) \to F_{X}(x)$ pointwise, for all points $x$ at which $F_X$ is continuous. Since $F_X$ is monotonic, it has at most countably many discontinuities, so $F_{X_n}(x) \to F_{X}(x)$ may fail for at most countably many $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Since, $P(|X| > t) = 1 - F_{|X|}(t)$, the same holds here.